# Where can I find a good definition of a Software construct?

Tags: terminology

I have scoured for 2 hours now across the internet, I have found courses with modules on software constructs but no clear definition only hints as to what one is.

As far as I understand the definition it is an object that can be defined with a purpose for example a TCP/IP connection uses a Port which is a Software construct.

Can anyone refer me to a full definition or give a more robust one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_(philosophy_of_science)

Then replace "Ideal" with "Software".

---

TCP is a protocol.  The software that implements this protocol is a software construct.

IP is a protocol.  The software that implements this protocol is a software construct.

IP uses IP addresses.  These are a software construct.  An IP Address has (almost) no physical reality, it's a relationship between a host and a network.  It is written in a file and the state of some magnetic media is a physical manifestation of the software construct.

IP connections use a Port.  These are a software construct  An IP Port is a relationship between messages, buffers, sending software and receiving software.  It has (almost) no physical reality; it's a state that will  be true of memory components that correctly implement the IP protocol.

Indeed.  All Software can be called examples of Software Construct.  Software itself is an idealization, so trying to subdivide "Construct" and "Software Constuct" is rather silly.  They're all idealizations.

Physical manifestations of software is the state of bits on magnetic disks, optical CD's or in semiconductor memory.

Comment: Maybe some use of "Abstraction" is proper here.

Comment: The example doesn't seem to be robust, I am looking for something preferably with examples in a information systems environment.

Comment: @Hugh: "Software Construct" has the exact same meaning as "Constuct" in the wikipedia article.  Anything in software -- anything -- is a "Software Construct".  It's a philosophical term.   Any software is a robust, concrete example of a software construct.  What more are you expecting?  Please give some criteria to clarify what you mean by "robust".

Comment: "A software construct is an ideal object which the existence of which may be said to depend upon a subject's mind." There are no examples and the definition is cursory as apposed to giving a more detailed definition with a detailed example.

Comment: @Hugh:  Any piece of software is an example of a software construct.  Any piece of software.  That's an indefinite number of examples.  What more do you need?  Do you want a list of all pieces of software?

Comment: That is perfect thank you and I may add in my opinion a great addition to the internet.